# Easiest way to show sequence $e^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I don't want to use the definition, is there an easier way?

Like, in the case of limits of functions, it is pretty easy to say by the composition theorem.

Is there any such theorem in case of sequences too?

Comment: A sequence is a function.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, sequence is a function from $\mathbb{N}$. But the theorem is for continuous functions only. So how can you talk about continuity when your domain is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Now *that* would make a good question, although it is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, if its duplicate. Please mark it as duplicate. But my answer answers my question.

Comment: Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881876/can-a-function-with-infinitely-many-holes-in-the-domain-still-be-continuous/2881901#2881901

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

As exponential function is continuous and "limit of the function"=function of the limit" for a continuous function, so$$\lim_n e^{1/n}=e^{\lim_n 1/n}=e^0=1.$$

Comment: Why down vote?.

Comment: Your answer is not at all legible. I am asking about sequences. So I presume, that limit, in this case means the number to which the sequence is convergent. But then how could you take the limit in the exponent?

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. More effort is needed in terms of formatting and clearly explaining the concept in words

Comment: Thats what I am asking. My question is about sequences, not functions.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Yes..I know.Tha's my answer read again

Comment: @GeorgeThomas  It has already editted..!

Comment: @Empty, I can't still see the hint. It clearly restates what I have not asked you to state, that is limit of functions. I am talking about limit of sequences.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Take, $f(x)=e^x$.Find $\displaystyle \lim_n f(1/n)$

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Do you know, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$, if $f$ is a continuous function ??

Comment: Yup, but not for a sequence. See my answer. Thanks for answering, but it was just a case of misunderstanding.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal What's your problem? Take $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=1/x$ and take the limit as $x\to \infty$ and use my 2nd last comment to evaluate the limit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81804/discussion-between-aditya-agarwal-and-empty).

Comment: Definitely sequence is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If you still unable to understand then please wait for another answer from other members..!!

Comment: @Empty. sequence is a function from N. But the theorem is for continuous functions only. So how can you talk about continuity when your domain is N?

Comment: I've already stated in my above comment , which you have to take $f$ and $g$. Do you think $f$ is not continuous on $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: I cannot continue this discussion here, I am only going to reply on the chat now.

Comment: I'm willing to upvote it now after edits

Answer (score 3):

$$1<e^{\frac1n}<3^{\frac1n}=(1+2)^{\frac1n}<1+\dfrac{2}{n}\to1$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since the **function whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$** converges to $1$ (By composiotion theorem). The sequence of the same functional rule should, too.

Since, we know that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$, so that $|f(n)-L|<\epsilon$ for **$n>N$**, So for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$, so that $|f(n)-L|<\epsilon$ for **$n \in \mathbb{I}>N$**. So the sequence converges too.
That is, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$$ too.

Comment: If anything is wrong with my answer, or is irrelevant, please explain, the downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $e^{1/n}=1+A_n.$ We have $A_n>0.$ From the Binomial Theorem we have  $$e=(1+A_n)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom {n}{j}(A_n)^j\geq \sum_{j=0}^1\binom {n}{j}(A_n)^j=1+nA_n.$$ Therefore  $\frac {e-1}{n}\geq A_n.$ This also works if we replace $e$ with any number greater than $1.$