# Open set in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that the following set is open:

$$U := \{(a,b,c,d)∈\Bbb{R}^4 : |ad-bc|>1\}$$
I know I have to show that there is an open ball at every point in the set, but don't know how to show this.

Comment: Have you tried to show this? Where do you get stuck? Can you find open balls around specific points, like for example only those where $b = 0$ or $c = 0$? Alternatively, are you familiar with "the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function is open"?

Comment: Would not it be easier to show that U is [inverse image of an open set (with $f$ continuous)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843909/prove-that-the-inverse-image-of-an-open-set-is-open)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tha map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}: (a,b,c,d) \mapsto \lvert ad-bc \rvert$ is continuous, because it is a composition of $\lvert {}\cdot{} \rvert$, which is continuous, and a polynomial expression. Hence $$f^{-1}((1,+\infty)) = \{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4: \lvert ad-bc \rvert > 1 \}$$ is open.