# If a function f is continuous the inverse image of an open set is an open set

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

This question was already asked.

Let $ X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-empty, open set and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

[Prove that the inverse image of an open set is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843909/prove-that-the-inverse-image-of-an-open-set-is-open)

Here is the proof by DiegoMath.

> Take $x_0\in f^{-1}(M)$, then $f(x_0)\in M$.
>
> Since $M$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(f(x_0),r)\subset M$.
>
> Now, choose any $0<\varepsilon\leq r$, since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\in B(f(x_0),\epsilon)$ whenever $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$.
>
> Note that if $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$, then $f(x)\in B(f(x_0),\varepsilon)\subset M$, thus $f(x)\in M$, moreover, $x\in f^{-1}(M)$, thus $B(x_0,\delta)\subset f^{-1}(M)$, then $f^{-1}(M)$ is open.

I do not understand why showing that $B(x_0,\delta)\subset f^{-1}(M)$, is sufficient to show that $f^{-1}(M)$ is open . Moreover, is it really true that $f(x)\in M$ for any x?

Comment: Where does it say that $f(x)\in M$ for any $x?$

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a set $A$ being open (in a metric space) is that for every point $a\in A$, there is some open ball around $a$ that is contained in $A$.  This is what the $B(x_0,\delta)\subseteq f^{-1}(M)$ is checking.  $B(x_0,\delta)$ is an open ball and it is inside $f^{-1}(M)$.

As for why $f(x)\in M$, by construction, $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$, so by continuity, $f(x)\in B(f(x_0),\varepsilon)$ and since $\varepsilon\leq r$, $f(x)\in B(f(x_0),\varepsilon)\subseteq B(f(x_0),r)$, so $f(x)\in B(f(x_0),r)$.  However, $B(f(x_0),r)\subseteq M$ by assumption, so $f(x)\in M$.